# Java - Writing, reading and modifying strings with parameters

Tags: java, string

So, I'm doing a project and now I have a question, so I would like your help :)

First, I already know how to write and read a .txt file, but I want something more than just x.hasNext().

I want to know how could write, read and modify a .txt file like .ini does. What? Simple (I think):

First, write a file like this:

```
[client1]
name=Bill Gates
nick=Uncle Bill
number=123456789
[client2]
name=Steve Jobs
nick=Stevie
number=987654321
```

And so many other parameters, just like above, but when I'm wanting to read a specific one (like name or nick of a certain "client") I can do it with easy (Ok, I know it will not be easy, but I think you understood :D)

So, if you already know what I want to learn, please, teach me :) If you don't, please explain me what you didn't understood :D

Thanks in advance for every helping

Comment: Some file formats have specialized libraries for parsing and editing them. You can also write your own to handle it in a manner that you want. For INI files, there's [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/). Under the hood they'll still be using the same file reading/access functionality like using a buffered reader, but they present a nicer interface to the files.

Comment: IMHO if there is a library for parsing a kind of file, then use it, don't write your own

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - in this case, it could arguably be both easier and more effective just to dash off your own, simple .ini parser class.  IMHO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you describe is for a Windows .ini file, back from Windows 3.x days:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Perhaps the closest thing to a "standard format" in Java is a "properties" file; typically in the format "name=value":

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

If you were to write your own program and invent your own initialization file format, would *not* use an .ini file.  Instead, I would recommend:

1) simple properties file (if possible)

```
 ... otherwise ...
```

2) an XML file (if you need multi-level, structured data)

However, if you want to read and write existing .ini files for an existing application, I would either:

1) write my own .ini parser (it isn't difficult)

```
 ... or ...
```

2) Download and run a library likke ini4j:

- http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

'Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The commons-configuration project from apache supports INI file formats:

```
HierarchicalINIConfiguration config = new HierarchicalINIConfiguration(file);
Set<String> sectionNames = config.getSections();
SubnodeConfiguration section = config.configurationAt(sectionName);
String value = section.getString(keyName);
```

Check out the javadocs, it's pretty easy to use.